# Why does this python code work?

Tags: python

```
# this code I don't understand 
def cls():                       #if statement freaks me out
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
```

I understand that it works but not WHY it works. After several hours of perusing google, python docs, and stackoverflow, I am none the wiser. I have been unable to find anything explaining that manner of using an IF statement in a function call like this. I have run it under 2.7 and 3.5 so it does not appear to be specific to a particular version. I have seen similar stuff done with for loops  sort of get that it might be a standard way of doing things. I kind of like it myself. Just don't understand how it works.

I am confused about how the IF statement is evaluated within system call and I am especially confused about the syntax of the IF statement. I have not seen that syntax in any of the documentation I have read.

Python is completely new to me. So forgive me if this is bonehead simple. But I don't get it.

Comment: `os.system` expects a command, the inline `if` generates one.

Comment: It's just an if statement. `system` expects only a string and the expression delivers it whichever way the if goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are more familiar with C-like languages and their ternary operator, Python's `a if b else c` is similar to `b ? a : c`. Therefore, the code above says:

```
if we are on NT/Windows
  then use `cls`
else (for Linux, etc) use `clear`
```

The result is then passed to the `os.system()` command to perform the OS-specific operation.

Here is [some tutorial information on this subject](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html).

Comment: Wow...y'all are fast!

Comment: Was not allowed to edit my first line comment. Hit enter too soon.

The c analogy works for me.
I knew what the code was doing but did not know this syntax and was not smart enough to find he docs. Thank you very much for both the answer and the link.

Answer (score 4):

```
A if C else B
```

This first evaluates C; if it is true, A is evaluated to give the
result, otherwise, B is evaluated to give the result.

This shortcut conditional expression syntax was added since Python 2.5
[Check it here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html)

There's similar syntax in other languages, taking Java for example:
`min = (a<b)? a: b` which checks whether a is smaller than b, it returns a if a is smaller, otherwise returns b. BTW, it is call **ternary operator** in java.

In your case:

`'cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear'` it checks whether `os.name` equals to string `nt`, if it is, it returns `cls`, otherwise it returns `clear`

Comment: Thanks. The link was especially helpful. Ken Y-N used the C style operator to explain (b ? a : c) which I thought was a good analogy too.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` expression is not executed inside of the system call. It is executed *before* the system call. Your code is equivalent to

```
command = 'cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear'
os.system(command)
```

The if expression itself is only a short form for the if statement

```
if os.name=='nt':
    command = 'cls'
else:
    command = 'clear'
os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 3):

this inline `if - else` is the `python` version of ternary operator.

in languages like C/C++/Java/JavaScript you would write

```
a = b > c ? 10 : 20
```

in python you would write the same as

```
a = 10 if b > c else 20
```

you can use the same construct to pass parameters to functions.

in C/C++

```
foo(b > c ? 10 : 20)
```

in python

```
foo(10 if b > c else 20)
```